# Does there exist a real differentiable function f with the following propertie simultaneously?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Does there exist a real differentiable function f with the following property simultaneously?

if ‎put ‎$‎f_n:=f(n)‎$‎ and ‎‎$‎f^\prime_n:=f^\prime(n)‎$,‎$‎‎\mathbb{N}‎\subseteq ‎D_f‎$‎‎‎‎,then the sequence ‎$‎f_n‎$ ‎is convergent, ‎$‎f^\prime_n‎$‎ and ‎$‎\sum_{n=1}^{‎\infty‎}f^\prime_n‎$‎ are divergent but ‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎$‎f^\prime_n+\sum_{k=1}^{‎n}f^\prime_k$‎‎ ‎is ‎convergent‎ as ‎$‎n\to {‎\infty‎}‎$.

Comment: Point on notation: Introducing $f_n,f_n'$ makes the problem harder to read, not easier, because you have to remember what they are. Better to leave it as $f(n),f'(n).$

Comment: My edit was for a typo on a subscript in the last line: Changed $\sum_{k=1}^nf'_n\;$ to $\;\sum_{k=1}^nf'_k$.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Apply the following, with $f'(n)=B(n).$

Theorem. For a real sequence $(B(n))_n$ let $S(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n B(n)$ and $T(n)=B(n)+S(n).$  If $S(n)$ does not converge then $T(n)$ does not converge. Equivalently if $T(n)$ converges then $S(n)$ converges.

Proof: Suppose $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}T(n).$ By contradiction suppose that $(S(n))_n$ does not converge. Then (i) there exists $U>L$ such that $S(n)>U$ for infinitely many $n$, or (ii) there exists $U<L$  such that $S(n)<U$ for infinitely many $n.$ Case (ii) can be converted to Case (i) by replacing $B(n)$ with $-B(n)$ so it suffices to consider Case (i).

Take $d>0$ with $3d<(U-L)$ and take $n_1$ such that $n\geq n_1\implies |T(n)-L|<d.$ Take $n_2\geq n_1$ such that $S(n_2)>U.$ We need the following Lemma:

Lemma. There exists $n>n_2$ such that $S(n)<U.$

Proof of Lemma: By contradiction, suppose $S(n)>U$ for all $n\geq n_2.$ Then for every $j\geq 0$ we have $$L+d>T(n_2+j+1)=S(n_2+j)+2B(n_2+j+1)>U+2B(n_2+j+1)$$ implying  $B(n_2+j+1)<-(U-L-d)/2<-d.$

But then for positive integer $k>(S(n_2)-U)/d$ we have $S(n_2+k)=S(n_2)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}B(n_2+j+1)<S(n_2)-kd<U,$ contrary to $S(n_2+k)>U.$

So the lemma is proved.

By the Lemma let $n_3>n_2$ such that $S(n_3)<U.$ Now $S(n)>U$ for infinitely many $n$ so let $n_4$ be the $least$ $n>n_3$ such that $S(n)>U.$ Then $S(n_4-1)<U<S(n_4)=S(n_4-1)+B(n_4)$ so $$B(n_4)>0.$$ And we have $L+d>T(n_4)$ because $n_4>n_1.$  Therefore $$L+d>T(n_4)=S(n_4)+B(n_4)>S(n_4)>U>L+d$$ a contradiction.

Comment: We can modify this to show that if $r\geq 1$ and $V(n+1)=rB(n+1)+S(n)=rB(n+1)+\sum_{j=1}^n B(j)$ then $V(n)$ converges iff $S(n)$ converges..... For $ r<1$ this does not work,e.g., $ r=1/2 $ and $B(n)=2(-1)^{n+1},$ when $B(n+1)/2+S(n)=1$ for all $n.$

Comment: Interesting Q on sequences. At first I thought I had to find $n_3>n_2$ with $S(n_3)<L+3d.$  Later, my first proof  of the Lemma was much more complicated.